# form_validation returning false : codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can anyone help me why my if code ($ this-> form_validation-> run () == FALSE) always returning FALSE even all fields are valid.

I have already loaded form_validation, url etc. the application is already working on a web server but when I deploy the application in localhost I hang on this error (from_validation always return false).

Here is my form:

```
    <?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
$email = array(
    'name'  => 'email',
    'id'    => 'email',
    'class'=> 'input',
    'value' => set_value('email'),
    'maxlength'=> 80,
    'size'  => 27,
);
$password = array(
    'name'  => 'password',
    'id'    => 'password',
    'class' => 'input',
    'value' => set_value('password'),
    'size'  => 27,
);
?>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span8">
    <b>Bienvenu!</b>
    <p>Identifier-vous pour Accèder à Votre Compte</p>
    <p>et Profiter de Nos Services en Ligne </p>
    <?php $connect='users/login'; ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="error"><strong><?=$this->session->flashdata('flashSuccess')?></strong></div>
<div class="login">
<?php $attributes = array('name' => 'loginf', 'autocomplete' => 'off' ); ?>
<?php echo form_open($connect,$attributes );?>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
        <?php echo form_label('Adresse Email', $email['id']); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="span5">
        <?php echo form_input($email); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
        <?php echo form_label('Mot de passe', $password['id']); ?>
    </div> 
    <div class="span5">
        <?php echo form_password($password); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        <input class="btn"  name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Connexion" />
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<?php echo form_close()?>
```

And my controller where the form_validation always returns false:

```
<?php
function login(){
    $this->load->model('User_m');
    $auto=FALSE;
    $email=strtolower($this->input->post('email'));
    $found="@bmc.com";
    $res=strpos($email,$found) ;
    if($res > 0){
        $role=$this->User_model->getRole(strtolower($this->input->post('email')));
        $tiers=$this->User_model->getTiers(strtolower($this->input->post('email')));
            if($role=="VEND" && $tiers==""){
                $auto=TRUE;
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'xss_clean|trim|required|valid_email');  
            }else{
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'xss_clean|trim|required|valid_email|callback_conten');
            }
    }else{
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'xss_clean|trim|required|valid_email|callback_conten');
    }       
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'xss_clean|trim|required|min_length[6]|max_length[20]|callback_password_check');
    $this->_email = $this->input->post('email');
    $s_pass=$this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'));
    $this->_password = sha1($this->_salt .$s_pass);
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){   
        $this->tmpl_login['success']=NULL;
        $this->tmpl_login['auth']='style="display:block"';
        $this->tmpl_login['p_o']='style="display:none"';
        $this->layout->view_menu_top('menul');
        $this->layout->view('compte/login',$this->tmpl_login);
    }else{           
        $this->auth->login('email');
        $dv=$this->find_date_visit();
        if($auto==FALSE){$this->_SendDynamiqueMessage($this->_email);} 
        $this->session->set_userdata('name',$this->find_name_user($this->_email));
        $this->session->set_userdata('quality',$this->find_quality_user($this->_email));
        $this->session->set_userdata('date_visite',$dv);
        $this->session->set_userdata('email',$this->_email);
        $user_agent = get_browser(null, true);
        $this->db->query("insert into us_connexion values ('". $this->_email."',sysdate,'". $user_agent['platform']."','". $user_agent['parent']."')");
        if(!$dv){
            $this->session->set_userdata('date_visite','premier visite');
            redirect('users/password');    
        }               
        redirect('users/index');
    }
}

?>
```

PS: I used the codeigniter 2.0.2 version.
Any help please!
Thinks.

Comment: Why don't you echo `validation_errors()` to see why it is returning false? `if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){ echo validation_errors(); ... etc }`

Comment: Hi Alex, I add echo validation_errors(); but it shows an empty string: string '' (length=0)

Comment: I just noticed you are using custom form_validation methods namely: `callback_password_check`, and `callback_conten`. I bet that those are the ones that are evaluating your `form_validation` to FALSE as the rest of the methods from CI *will* return an error message. I bet that you aren't setting the error message in these custom functions hence the empty string and FALSE form validation. Can you post those methods?